# Knockout css binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a button that I want to toggle the class when clicked.

This is what I currently have.

```
 <table>
     <tbody data-bind="foreach: item ">
      <tr>
         <td><a data-bind="click:    $parent.selectItem,    text:   Name, css: { 'whitishBtn button_small': selected(), 'greenishBtn button_small': !selected() }"></a></td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
```

it almost works. When green it works as expected but only has whitishBtn class when white.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

selected() ? 'greenishBtn button_small':'whitishBtn button_small'"